# Python - Display Every Permutation of a List or Set of Strings

Tags: python, string, permutation

As an example, I have the following list:

```
['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']
```

By my reckoning, there should be 26 combinations i.e.

```
ABCDEFGHIJKL
ABCDEFJKLGHI
ABCGHIDEFJKL
ABCGHIJKLDEF
ABCJKLDEFGHI
ABCJKLGHIDEF
...
```

How would I do this in Python?

Thanks

Comment: 26? How'd you get that number?

Comment: There's actually 4! = 4*3*2 = 24 permutations...

Comment: My maths is poor after 11pm :-(

Answer (score 3):

You're describing the basic use of [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> L = ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']
>>> for permutation in itertools.permutations(L):
...     print ''.join(permutation)
...     
ABCDEFGHIJKL
ABCDEFJKLGHI
ABCGHIDEFJKL
ABCGHIJKLDEF
...
JKLGHIDEFABC
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that uses `itertools`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print list(itertools.permutations(['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL'], 4))
[('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'), ('ABC', 'DEF', 'JKL', 'GHI'), ('ABC', 'GHI', 'DEF', 'JKL'), ('ABC', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'DEF'), ('ABC', 'JKL', 'DEF', 'GHI'), ('ABC', 'JKL', 'GHI', 'DEF'), ('DEF', 'ABC', 'GHI', 'JKL'), ('DEF', 'ABC', 'JKL', 'GHI'), ('DEF', 'GHI', 'ABC', 'JKL'), ('DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'ABC'), ('DEF', 'JKL', 'ABC', 'GHI'), ('DEF', 'JKL', 'GHI', 'ABC'), ('GHI', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'JKL'), ('GHI', 'ABC', 'JKL', 'DEF'), ('GHI', 'DEF', 'ABC', 'JKL'), ('GHI', 'DEF', 'JKL', 'ABC'), ('GHI', 'JKL', 'ABC', 'DEF'), ('GHI', 'JKL', 'DEF', 'ABC'), ('JKL', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'), ('JKL', 'ABC', 'GHI', 'DEF'), ('JKL', 'DEF', 'ABC', 'GHI'), ('JKL', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'ABC'), ('JKL', 'GHI', 'ABC', 'DEF'), ('JKL', 'GHI', 'DEF', 'ABC')]
>>> print len(list(itertools.permutations(['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL'], 4)))
24
```